# Running a Stream on Flink Mini Cluster (1.11) and AvroKryoSerializerUtils are not working

Tags: apache-flink

I'm running into an issue when testing a stream on the flink mini cluster in my integration test.
The stream maps a generated Avro SpecificRecord Pojo Class (Java).

The stream job is written in Scala.

The flink runtime is crashing because it cannot instantiate the `org.apache.flink.formats.avro.utils.AvroKryoSerializerUtils`

Here is the stack trace:

```
stack: java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.apache.flink.formats.avro.utils.AvroKryoSerializerUtils
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not instantiate org.apache.flink.formats.avro.utils.AvroKryoSerializerUtils.
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.AvroUtils.getAvroUtils(AvroUtils.java:53)
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.runtime.kryo.KryoSerializer.buildKryoRegistrations(KryoSerializer.java:572)
```

I think the problem is that Flink is unable to serialize the Avro Pojo Class because the Class has multiple nested Avro Pojo Classes in it.

I tried to add all the type informations for all nested Pojo Class types but still running into the same issue.

So now I wonder if anyone made a Flink Job work with a generated Avro Pojo Class with nested Avro Pojo Classes. All classes inherit the type SpecificRecord and are generated from a avro schema.

Is there some kind of special Serializer that needs to be written? Is there any documentation or example out there for such a Serializer that deals with multiple nested Pojo Classes in Scala or Java?

Or is it a different problem altogether?

Many Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

The issue may arise if `flink-avro` is not in classpath. If you are using Avro anyways, I'd [disable Kryo completely](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/types_serialization.html#disabling-kryo-fallback) to catch more subtle errors.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Thats what I checked first. Please see my answer where I mention what was the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I made it work by doing the parsing inside a process function.

I had to parse a string to json and then to a Record Class for one specific field of the SpecificRecord class which should end up in the DataSink.

The parsing of the json is now implemented within another ProcessFuncton and now it works. Before I had the parsing in a map directly applied to the DataStream.